# application defined or object defined error whey copying data into array

Tags: arrays, vba, named-ranges

I am used to assigning ranges to arrays. However, for some reason right now I am constantly getting an application or object defined error (the first code line below). The second line below works fine. It is identical to the first line except I just copy the range showing all the variables exist.

I have checked in the watch window, arrActuals is Variant/Variant(). Adding .Value at the end of the first line did not solve the error either. Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
  arrActuals = wkbOVHFile.Sheets(szAOPPage).Range(Cells(iStartCopy, IntActOVHCol), Cells(iEndCopy, IntActOVHCol))
                                            
wkbOVHFile.Sheets(szAOPPage).Range(Cells(iStartCopy, IntActOVHCol), Cells(iEndCopy, IntActOVHCol)).Copy
```

Comment: Try `arrActuals = wkbOVHFile.Sheets(szAOPPage).Range(wkbOVHFile.Sheets(szAOPPage).Cells(iStartCopy, IntActOVHCol), wkbOVHFile.Sheets(szAOPPage).Cells(iEndCopy, IntActOVHCol)).Value`. To avoid such long lines (improve readability), rather use variables e.g.: `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wkbOVHFile.Sheets(szAOPPage)` and then do `arrActuals = ws.Range(ws.Cells(iStartCopy, IntActOVHCol), ws.Cells(iEndCopy, IntActOVHCol)).Value`.

Answer (score 1):

`Cells` without a qualifying worksheet object defaults to the active sheet, so your code fails when `wkbOVHFile.Sheets(szAOPPage)` is not the active sheet.

More robust like this:

```vb
Dim rng As Range

With wkbOVHFile.Sheets(szAOPPage)
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(iStartCopy, IntActOVHCol), _
                     .Cells(iEndCopy, IntActOVHCol))
End With

arrActuals = rng.Value
rng.Copy
```